# Unable to create relationships importing a csv in Neo4j

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am unable to create relationships importing .csv files in Neo4j

The nodes I have are for Medical Providers and Medical Conditions

The relationship is Provider-[TREATS]->Condition

Here is a subset of my providers csv:

```
Provider,ProviderID,Office,Street,City,State,Zip,Phone
Dr. Mxxxxi MD,1,The xxx Hospital,1xxx xxx Hwy,Ft Wright,KY,4xxxxx,(xxx) xxx-3304
```

Here is a subset of my conditions csv:

```
condition,conditionID
Acute Leukemia,1
Acute Lymphoid Leukemia,2
Acute Myeloid Leukemia,3
Adrenal Gland Cancer,4
....
```

Here is a subset of my relations csv:

```
ProviderID,ConditionID
1,1
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
1,9
...
```

Here are the import/create statements:

```
// Create providers
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///providers.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Provider {provider: row.Provider, providerID: row.ProviderID, officeName: row.OfficeName, street:row.Street,  city:row.City, state:row.State,  zip:row.Zip,  phone: row.Phone});
```

Added 1 label, created 1 node, set 7 properties, statement completed in 283 ms

```
// Create conditions
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///conditions.csv" AS row
CREATE (:Condition {Condition: row.condition, ConditionID: 
row.conditionID});
```

Added 100 labels, created 100 nodes, set 200 properties, statement completed in 262 ms.

I created indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Provider(providerID);
CREATE INDEX ON :Condition(conditionID);
```

This is the import/create relationship statement and result:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///ProviderConditionsTreated.csv" AS row
MATCH (p:Provider { providerID: row.ProviderID})
WITH p
MATCH (c:Condition { conditionID: p.ConditionID})
CREATE (p)-[t:TREATS]->(c);
```

(no changes, no records)

I have also tried this with no records

```
MATCH (p:Provider { providerID: row.ProviderID})
MATCH (c:Condition { conditionID: row.ConditionID})
CREATE (p)-[t:TREATS]->(c);
```

(no changes, no records)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two issues with your import query:

1. The Cypher language is [case-sensitive](https://neo4j.com/developer/cypher-query-language/) for labels, types and property names. In your providers.csv file, the `ProviderID` attribute starts with an uppercase character, but in the conditions.csv file, the `conditionID` attribute starts with a lowercase one. While loading them with the `LOAD CSV` commands, these are actually changed to `providerId` and `ConditionId`. It's best to keep these consistent both for the CSV files and for the vertex properties.
2. You should not use `WITH p` as you will no longer be able to access the `row` variable. This is fixed in your last query. However, even that can be simplified by using a single `MATCH` clause.

In conclusion, the following query worked for me:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///relations.csv" AS row
MATCH
  (p:Provider { providerID: row.ProviderID}),
  (c:Condition { ConditionID: row.ConditionID})
CREATE (p)-[t:TREATS]->(c);
```

> Created 4 relationships, completed after 110 ms.

Comment: I fixed the cases and ran the create relationship statement and it ran perfectly! Thanks Gabor!

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for the detailed question & the reproducible problem statement.